# Как заставить, чтоб Dynamic Web Project работал с Tomcat и Derby DB?

Tags: java, tomcat

Привет всем!
Уже замучился и никак не могу сделать проект.
Нужна помощь сообщества.

> Что мне нужно сделать?

Мне нужно создать Web проект на Java, который будет работать с сервером Tomcat и Derby базой данных.

> Что я сделал?

Создал директорию home которая находится на C:\ - (`C:\home`). В эту директорию поместил следующее: Tomcat, Derby, eclipse, jdk8 и workspace для проекта.

Так выглядит моя архитектура - все, что нужно для работы с проектом:

```
C:\home\apache-tomcat-8.0.36,<br>
C:\home\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin,<br>
C:\home\eclipse,<br>
C:\home\jdk8,<br>
C:\home\workspace<br>
```

---

1. Создал проект который называется ManagementStudent (Dynamic Web Application)
2. Добавил в Эклипсе Tomcat v8.0 из директории - `C:\home\apache-tomcat-8.0.36`
3. Создал новый source folder с названием DBCreator который находится в узле ManagementStudent

   1. Создал новый *.java-файл под названием CreateDatabase.java, его расположение: `ManagementStudent/DBCreator/dbcreate/CreateDatabase.java`
4. Сделал ссылку в Эклипсе для ManagementStudent от derbyclient.jar, который находится на: `home/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbyclient.jar`
5. Написал соответствующий код для проекта и запускаю startNetworkServer.bat, который находится на: `C:/home/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/bin/startNetworkServer.bat`
6. Из Эклипса запускаю CreateDatabase.java, который находится на: `ManagementStudent/DBCreator/dbcreate/CreateDatabase.java`

   1. В этом классе есть метод main и он ответственный за создание БД.
   2. База Данных создается успешно, которая находится в: `C:\home\db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin\bin\StudentDB`
7. После чего копирую ее в корень ManagementStudent: ManagementStudent/StudentDB

---

После процесса создания написал класс для проверок DML и все работает хорошо.

Теперь я создаю следующее:

1. StudentServlet.java, который расположен в: `ManagementStudent/src/web/students/Student.java`
2. Student.html, который расположен в: `ManagementStudent/WebContent/Student.html`

После этого:

1. Запускаю Tomcat
2. Запускаю Derby
3. Открываю веб-страницу и набираю: `http://localhost:8080/ManagementStudent/StudentServlet`
4. Ввожу данные которые хочу передать на сервер, а потом их сохранить в БД

И сталкиваюсь со следующей проблемой: данные попадают на сервлет без проблем, но когда сервлет пытается их передать в Базу Данных, выпадает куча ошибок.

> После того как я загуглил - понял одно. Что мне нужно отконфигурировать Tomcat для Derby с помощью web.xml, который находится в `/ManagementStudent/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml` и context.xml который я должен создать в `/ManagementStudent/WebContent/META-INF/context.xml`
>
> А также - нужно скопировать derby.jar и derbyClient.jar в директорию /lib которая находится в Tomcat: (`C:\home\apache-tomcat-8.0.36\lib`), и отконфигурировать.

Кто нибудь знает как все это делается так, чтоб оно заработало. Потому что я уже и так и этак пытаюсь, но никак не получается.

Могу выслать свой мини-проект, если надо будет.

Заранее Благодарю!!!

Небольшой принт-скрин моего узла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]